# Spring data neo4j : count relation By EndNode ID

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using a spring data neo4j 5.0.0.

My model is a `(user)-[:ATTEND]-(meeting)` and `ATTEND` is a RelationshipEntity.
user have attend relationship, meeting does not have relationship.

```
@Relationship(type = "ATTEND")
Set<AttendMeeting> attendMeetings = new HashSet<>();
```

RelationshipEntity code.

```
@Setter @Getter @ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@RelationshipEntity(type = "ATTEND")
public class AttendMeeting {
    @GraphId private Long id;
    @JsonIgnore
    @StartNode private User user;
    @EndNode private Meeting meeting;
}
```

So I just wannna attend count by meetingId.

Is it possible without Query?

when I run on `repository.countByMeetingId` method
auto creation query is

`` MATCH (m:`Meeting`) WHERE m.`id` = { `meeting_id_0` } MATCH (n)-[r0:`ATTEND`]->(m) RETURN COUNT(r0) ``

I expect `id(m)` but generated query is `` m.`id' ``.

Can I make countByRelationShipEntityId?
How can I auto generate code like this.
`MATCH ()-[r:ATTEND]-(m:Meeting) WHERE ID(m) = {0} RETURN COUNT (r)`

Thanks for your answer and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: It is currently not possible to achieve this without a custom query because the mapping assumes that it is a property like every other. What is your use case for having to use an `id`? Maybe there is another solution for your problem.

Comment: Query is a simple way but you know string is a not good to management. I just counting relation by meeting Id. how can I found relation count without query

Comment: Where does the id come from? Maybe you can query the count with the initial query and use it as a parameter of a QueryResult (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult).

Comment: I updated my question. Is is better to change model to meeting have attend relation? or make two relation like attend_to, attend_by.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently (SDN 5.0.1) no possibility to count on a given object e.g. `countByMeeting(Meeting meeting)` or let SDN handle id as a special property.
Please feel free to create an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH/

The only solution we can offer at the moment without providing a query is a count by related object property like `countByMeetingName(String meetingName)`

Edit: Issue created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1049